# Angular Pipe - access Component instance

Tags: angular

Inside my `TableComponent` I'm maintaining a dictionary to represent the checked rows.

```
private checkedRows: Dictionary<boolean> = {}; // { [id: string]: boolean }
```

---

I then have a method, used inside the template

```
isRowCheckDisabled(rowId: string): boolean {
   return (
      !this.checkedRows[rowId] && this.getCheckedRowsCount() >= this.selectionOpt.limit
   );
}

getCheckedRowsCount(): number {
   return Object.keys(this.checkedRows).length;
}
```

Template:

```
<td 
  ...
  [nzDisabled]="isRowCheckDisabled(row.id)"
  ...
</td>
```

---

I'd like to move this logic inside a *pure* (maybe?) `Pipe`.
However, without having direct access to the component fields, I'll have to implement it with a signature like

```
transform(
    rowId: string, 
    checkedRows: Dictionary<boolean>,
    selectionOpt: SelectionOpt | undefined): boolean
) { ... }
```

And use it like

```
[nzDisabled]="row.id | checked: checkedRows:selectionOpt"
```

Which isn't really "nice".

The question is, can the Pipe access the current Component context, and therefore its fields?
Is there a better way to do this? Should I stick with the method?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```js
constructor(cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    (cdRef as EmbeddedViewRef<Type<any>>).context
}
```